# Variable from ajax post not bringing correct results when inserted in a query

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel

I have a laravel project and I try to load html code inside a div (.load_content) with an ajax request..

Ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
$.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/project_post/',
           data:{id:id, param1:param1, param2:param2, param3:param3},
           success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('.load_content').html(data.html);
           }
});
```

My controller - I take the data from post and run a stored procedure

```
public function post(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request->input('id');
        $param1 = $request->input('param1');
        $param2 = $request->input('param2');
        $param3 = $request->input('param3');


$list = DB::select('exec Get_List ?, ?, ?, ?', [$id, $param1, $param2, $param3]);

$view = view('projekt_detail', ['list' => $list,])->render();

return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html' => $view));
}
```

The problem is that the query returns no results. If I hardcode the parameters in the exec statement I get the result I want.

If I do

```
$param_test1='pa';
$param_test2='pb';
$param_test3='pc';
```

and run this query

```
$list = DB::select('exec Get_List ?, ?, ?, ?', [$id, $param_test1, $param_test2, $param_test3]);
```

I get the results I want.
The wird part is that if I do this check

```
$param1 == $param_test1
```

it returns true. They have the same value but the one that comes from the post request brings no result from the database. Any ideas?
I also have to mention that I only have problem with the parameters that are strings. The id parameter that is a number works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After guessing and trying when I did

```
$param1 = urldecode($request->input('param1'));
..... same for other parameters .....
```

everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no reputation to let a comment.

In your post method, try to put dd($request->all()); before the $id set. This way you can see which values your method are receiving.

Another idea would be force the $id to be integer

```
$list = DB::select('exec Get_List ?, ?, ?, ?', [(int) $id, $param1, $param2, $param3]);
```

Comment: The id has no problem.. It passes correctly. The other parameters that are strings cause the issue, even if I try to cast them as a string.
Also my request object has the right values

Answer (score 0):

Change your AJAX a little bit:

```
contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
dataType: "json",
data : JSON.stringify({'id':id, 'param1':param1, 'param2':param2, 'param3':param3})
```

Then you can access the values like this:

```
$request->id
```

Your way of accessing may also work.

Comment: It didn't work.. same thing - no results. The query seems fine and identical of the one in my solution. But I get results only if I urldecode the parameters before executing the database query

Comment: There must be something wrong with the query then. Try to error_log f.e. `$request->id` does it show the correct value? If yes the request data is correctly given to the function and the problem is with the query, there I cant help. I recently started with laravel aswell.

Comment: P.S.: you could also try to use the built in laravel request helper function `request('id')`

Comment: I'll stick with the urldecode.. It doesn't cause any issue and the results are as they should be..
My idea came because if I loaded the parameteres of the query from url with jquery load it also worked.